# Regex - PascalCase to lower case with underscores

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to convert PascalCase property names such as `Is24Hour`, `Is512` to JSON-style lowercase with underscores (ie. `is_24_hour`, `is_512`) using C#.

So far I've got far but it doesn't work for multiple numbers.

```
([A-Z])([A-Z0-9][a-z])|([a-z0-9])([A-Z0-9])
```

With the replacement expression (`$1$3_$2$4`)

For example `"Is24Hour"` becomes `"Is_24_Hour"` (which is then lower-cased by `.ToLower()`).
but `"Is512"` becomes `"Is_51_2"`.

Comment: FYI, This is also called snake case. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [String.ToLower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx) for conversion into lowercase.

For the regex, the following [seems to work](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=3aa19c83-8e07-48ba-8949-694f826e8914):

```
((?<=.)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)|((?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+)
```

combined with the replacement expression:

```
_$1$2
```

Here's a full sample:

```
string strRegex = @"((?<=.)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)|((?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"Is24Hour" + "\n" + 
    @"Is512" + "\n" + @"A12Hour4" + "\n" + 
    @"23AHourDay12" + "\n" + @"An8DAY512";

string strReplace = @"_$1$2";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace).ToLower();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Sorry I forgot to add the replacement expression to my question :)

Comment: This does not work properly at all. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JOS1Jm). Even using the exact example that's provided results in an invalid result string. For example, `23AHourDay12` becomes `23_ahourday_12` with this code, but it should be `23_a_hour_day_12`.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. `FooBarBuzz` is converted into `foo_barbuzz`!

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution **does not work** for strings like "**23AHourDay12**", it produces "**23_ahourday_12**", but should "**23_a_hour_day_12**" (see the @vaindil comment)

Here is a solution using Linq, instead of Regex:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static string ToUnderscoreCase(this string str) {
        return string.Concat(str.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString())).ToLower();
    }
}
```

Thanks @vkobel github user. Source: https://gist.github.com/vkobel/d7302c0076c64c95ef4b

Answer (score 3):

```
public string PascalCaseToSnakeCase(string str) => Regex.Replace(str, "[A-Z0-9][0-9]*", "_$0").ToLower().Trim('_');
```

Comment: Does this handle the numbers within `Is24Hour` and `Is512` as wanted by the question?