# Single regex that changes camel-case to dash-separated lowercase

Tags: regex, pcre, sublimetext-snippet

I'm trying to write a SublimeText [snippet](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html) for javascript `import` statements.  I want the format the format to be like:

```
import MyFooBar from 'my-foo-bar';
```

The input to my regex is `MyFooBar`, and the output needs to be `my-foo-bar`.  I found an answer that almost works in [Regex - CamelCase to lower case with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951645/regex-camelcase-to-lower-case-with-underscores):

> Search for
>
> `((?<=.)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)|((?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+)`
>
> Replace with
>
> `-$1$2`

The answer said to just use javascript's `.toLowerCase()` method for the lowercasing, but SublimeText snippets use perl, of which I have the briefest of knowledge.  A quick search said that for lowercasing, I can use `\L` at the beginning of my replacement.

```
/((?<=.)[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)|((?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+)/\L-\1\2/g
```

This works on all but the first segment's character, so `MyFooBar` becomes `My-foo-bar`.

I thought maybe I could run two regexes in sequence, but either perl or Sublime doesn't recognize that.

Thoughts?

Edit:

When I say it uses perl, I just mean it uses a perl regex.  As far as I can tell, I can't actually execute arbitrary code; I can only specify a regex that perl can execute.

Here's the full text of my snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
import ${1:module} from '${2:./path/}${1/((?<=.)[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)|((?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+)/\L-\1\2/g}';
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>import</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Why does it *have* to be a regex? This would be more easily handled by a proper search-and-replace function, which perl has...

Comment: @cat I'm just learning how to create snippets, but http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions only shows one way to do replacements.

Comment: @anubhava OPs last sentence is the problem here. You run 2 regexes to correct the "error" on the first Character, which apparently does not work.

Comment: Would you please upload your current full snippet?

Comment: @revo I've updated the question

Comment: You either need a conditional replacement pattern (and PCRE does not support that) or check how to use two regexps on the same value at a row. BTW, are you sure it is PCRE? Not Boost?

Comment: That's the conclusion I'm starting to draw.  I had hoped there was some way to make a group match an imaginary hyphen, or make a replacement group loop, or something.  Thanks all for your help!

Comment: BTW, in real Boost, as in Notepad++, it would suffice to use `(?<a1>(?:(?<=\W)|(?<=^))[A-Z][a-z]*)|(?<a2>[A-Z][a-z]*)|(?<a3>(?<=[a-z])\d+)`  and replace with `\L(?{a1}$+{a1}:(?{a2}-$2:-$3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed RegEx to something more useful and probably simple.

** ***Updated***

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
import ${1:module} from '${2:./path/}${1/(^[A-Z][a-z]+|[a-z])([A-Z])/\L\1-\2/g}';
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>import</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: That'll prepend a `-` to my module file name.  I can just delete that, but that's basically what I have to do right now with replacing the first capitalized character.

Comment: @dfoverdx Oh yes, but when I do `enter` that extra dash goes away!

Comment: Weird that it does not for me... In fact, when I pressed enter, it replaced what I had entered with the regex'd value in both spots.

Comment: @dfoverdx Changed regex. Check it now.

Comment: So close.  I thought it worked until I tried "Environment".  If there is no second capital letter, then the word isn't replaced.  Not a big issue to just replace the first character.  Alas, I don't think this particular endeavor is possible.

Comment: I doubt if it could be possible. Since that dash is outside the regex and you can't make it conditional. It's always there. @dfoverdx

Comment: It is possible to make it conditional by changing `-\2` to `(?2-\2)`.
The full regex line:
`import ${1:module} from '${2:./path/}${1/(^[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z])([A-Z])?/\L\1(?2-\2)/g}';`

Answer (score 0):

Ugly (`substr()`) but works:

```
$x = "MyFooBar";
$x =~ s/(?:^|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]))(.)/-lc($1)/eg;
$x = substr($x, 1);
print $x;
// my-foo-bar
```

See a demo on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/O2GLbr).

Comment: Upvote but how about if you pass in something like MyFooBarID?

Answer (score 0):

This one took me a little while, but I believe it does what you want, all within a single regex:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>){
    chomp;
    s/([[:upper:]].*?)(?=(?:[[:upper:]]|$))/$+[0]!=length($_) ? lc($1).'-' : lc($1)/ge;
    print "$_\n";
}

__DATA__
MyCamelCase
AVeryLongCamelCaseStringWMXThat
```

Output:

```
my-camel-case
a-very-long-camel-case-string-w-m-x-that
```

Explanation: It looks for an upper case letter, and captures into `$1` that letter, along with all other letters until it sees another capital or end of string within a zero-width lookahead. in the substitution side, we use the `/e` modifier which means the right-hand side is an expression (executable code). If the end of the most recent match (`$+[0]`) is less than the length of the string, we do a lower (`lc()`) and append a `-`. If the length of the string is the same as the end of the last match, we lowercase it and we're done.

Comment: This won't work because the Sublime snippets aren't actually interpreting Perl---they're just using PCRE syntax.

Comment: I copied and pasted that into my snippet and ran it.  `import MyFooBar from './path/My[1]!=length$_-1 ? lcMy.'-' : lcMyFoo[1]!=length$_-1 ? lcFoo.'-' : lcFooBar[1]!=length$_-1 ? lcBar.'-' : lcBar';`  Good attempt though!

Comment: ahhh crap :) I missed the part about code not executing.

Comment: Well, it was the first time I've ever used `$+[0]` and `$-[0]`, so at least one of us gained from it :)